# Is it grammatically correct to say "time is ahead of me"

Tags: grammar

Just wanted to ask if it sounds natural to say "time is ahead of me".
What I want to express is how time will defeat me, and my disappointment at that.

Comment: *Time is ahead of me* sounds natural but is not a standard expression: it would only be comprehensible in context. However, it would probably be used in the sense "I have plenty of time" which is the **opposite** of what you want to express.

Comment: However, time is also behind you. If you're talking about the past. So the expression, barring context, may be wrong. It would make more sense to say that the future is ahead of you.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on our other site [ell.se], but you should [edit] it to provide more context. Why would you not simply use *time will defeat me*?

Answer (score 3):

> Does this sound natural to English speakers  to say "time is ahead of
>   me"?

Not really.  But I understand what you are trying to express in English.

The late Eva Peron of Argentina fame said it best:

**Time is my greatest enemy**. Evita Peron  [brainyquotes](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/evita_peron_126954)

An idiom you may consider:

**time and tide tarry for no man** or **time and tide wait for no man** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/time+and+tide+tarry+for+no+man)

> One cannot stop or slow the passage of time. A less common variant of
>   the phrase "**time and tide wait for no man**." If you're unhappy with
>   your life, make changes as soon as you can because time and tide tarry
>   for no man.

Comment: Actually, *time and tide wait ...* is much more common. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time+and+tide+*+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ctime%20and%20tide%20%2A%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btime%20and%20tide%20wait%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btime%20and%20tide%20waited%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btime%20and%20tide%20tarried%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btime%20and%20tide%20tarry%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btime%20and%20tide%20waits%20for%3B%2Cc0). And the original idiom was *time and tide stay for no man.*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others who have said that,
while “Time is ahead of me” is grammatically valid,
it would not generally be understood in the way that you want. 
As another variation, it sounds similar to

> I will be on vacation next week, and I’m going to the beach. 
>   So I have a good time ahead of me.

which also is obviously not what you want.

I expect that people would understand “time is against me”
as meaning “time is my enemy”.* 
In fact, Google suggests that [“time is against us”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22time+is+against+us%22)
may be somewhat more common than [“time is our enemy”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22time+is+our+enemy%22).

A similar-meaning idiom of comparable popularity
is ***time is not on my side***:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20is%20not%20on%20someone%27s%20side):
>
>   [Definition of time is not on someone’s side](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20is%20not%20on%20someone%27s%20side)
>   :
>     —used to say that a person will have less chance of success
>       because he or she has to do something very soon
>     // If we wait too long to buy the tickets,
>       the concert may be sold out:
>     *time is not on our side.*

________
* as mentioned [by lbf](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/471020/26083#471022).